# AngularJS - route is different when done through controller vs view

Tags: angularjs

I have the following route

```
$routeProvider
.when('/users/', { 
    auth: true,
    required: ['user_read'],
    templateUrl: '/js/app/views/templates/user/users.html',
    controller: 'UsersController'
})
```

In my LoginController, if it is successful login, I'm trying to redirect the user to that path using

```
$location.path('/users');
```

I also have a rootScope listener to check for permission

```
$rootScope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function (current) {
    console.log($route.current.$route);
}
```

Why is that last console log only showing

```
Object
    redirectTo: "/users/"
    __proto__: Object
```

when I do the redirect from the controller?

However, if I have a link on the template, it is showing

```
Object
    auth: true
    controller: "UsersController"
    reloadOnSearch: true
    required: Array[1]
    templateUrl: "/js/app/views/templates/user/users.html"
    __proto__: Object
```

The bottom output one is how I'm expecting the output to be.

Thanks,
Tee

Comment: One quick thought: "/users" will be treated differently than "/users/", but that may just be a typo in your post. It's hard to tell must more without seeing it running. Can you post a plunker?